# Is it possible to target multiple apps with firebase, but only one will display the notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new with FCM and I am still discovering its possibilities.
I wonder if it is the right tools to do what I want:

I would like to send a notification to all my users, to inform them about new informations for example.
The difficulty is that I want to target all the users of different apps (like 10 apps), and some of them may have more than one of my app installed.

So I do not want a user to have the same notification displayed multiple times (if he installed more than one of my app).

Is it something possible with Firebase?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! To achieve this, i recomand you using [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) not **`FCM`**. which it's an earlier version. Here is a [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) on how you can migrate from `FCM` to `GCM`.

To achieve this, all your 10 apps must use Firebase and all your users must be Firebase registered users. To send a notification to all devices, would mean then to select all the registration ids from that database, add them in an array and pass them further to `GCM`.

Note also, that strating with `GCM` 3.0 it's now possible to send a notification to all devices thanks to topics support. The app must suscribe to one or more topics and the server can send notifications to that topic without specifying individual devices. You can see here [Topic Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging).

Unfortunately, there is no way in which, with a single line of code, to send a notification to all of your users from all your apps. You can only send a notification to all your users that belong only to a single app. If you want that all of yours to get the same message, then you need to consider sending that particular message again, to all users that belong to each app. In this case, if a users is using more then one of your apps, will receieve that message for each app separately.

Comment: The problem is not about how to adress notification to all the users, we can send notification to all users of each app.
But I want to avoir that a user displays 3 times the same notification because he has 3 apps installed for example.

I guess that I need to use a shared file stored in external storage to store an id representing the notification, and each app receiving the message from FCM will check in this file if the message was alredy displayed by another app.

Comment: Could be be an option to create a common list of users from all your apps that will contain only the unique users and then pass it to `GCM`. I didn't actually tried, but it should work.

Comment: That link you posted is about migrating from GCM to FCM, which is Google's recommended course of action.  GCM is no longer maintained, and FCM is the supported solution for messaging.